# Is there a way to input different rel="author" and rel="publisher" attributes for a WP blog w/ multiple authors?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I'd really like to find a way or a plugin (that works) that inputs different rel="author" and/or rel="publisher" attributes for a blog with multiple authors.

That way, in a Google SERP, an article I wrote might show up as:

```
Jason Weber Meta Title of that post
(my picture) Meta description of that post
```

While another's post SERP might look like this:

```
Tracy Smith Meta Title of Tracy's post
(Tracy's picture) Meta description of Tracy's post
```

Does anybody have a suggestion for a plugin, hack, or fix that can accomplish this? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your website have many writer who wrote for your website and you want to show their individual google plus info at SERP. I think it might be helpful for you http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-plus-authorship/ . I didn't use it but its support multiple authors.

Comment: Hi iqbal.  This is the closest I've gotten with the various plugins I've tried.  I just have to tweak my Google+ page a little bit and it should be working fine.  Thanks for taking the time to read my question, and offer a reply -- appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes ... I just had to tweak my Google+ page and put a link back to my domain -- a step a lot of people forget.  But I'm having all the guest authors put their G+ profile # in their user settings.  Thanks again!